# Hbase command line cannot edit or delete

Tags: hbase

I'm very confuse why on the Hbase command line the input command can not be deleted,
If I made a mistake I have to in another prompt rewrite the command.
I feel this is very stupid,why?! Is my configuration wrong or other reason.
Or Base realy stupid?
I'm using contos 6.1,Hbase 0.94
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

HBase command line has history feature and it also can delete typed command before submittion

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor to the content you want to delete, and press the `Del` key.